# Why this error? Cannot we use format macro inside function parenthesis?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, fltk

Code:

```
fltk::frame::Frame::new(0,0, 300, 100, format!("side item {}", i));
```

Output Error:

```
the trait `std::convert::From<std::string::String>` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<&'static str>`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`format!()` yields a `String`, while [Frame::new](https://docs.rs/fltk/1.0.16/fltk/prelude/trait.WidgetBase.html#tymethod.new) expects an (optional) `&'static str`, i.e. a string slice that will be alive for the entirety of the program's lifecycle.

This pretty much means you can only use string literals. So no, you can not directly use `format!()`. Seems like FLTK does not intend for dynamically allocated strings to be used in this manner.

There is a hack to get around this using `Box::leak`. But be aware that it does what it says on the tin - it leaks memory, unless you reclaim it via `Box::from_raw()` after the widget is destroyed.

```rust
let leaked_title = &*Box::leak(format!("abc {}", 1).into_boxed_str())
fltk::frame::Frame::new(0,0, 300, 100, leaked_title);
```

Answer (score 2):

The default ::new constructor expects an `Into<Option<&'static str>>`, so if your `&str` is not static, you can use `with_label()` or `set_label()`.

```rust
fltk::frame::Frame::new(0,0, 300, 100, None).with_label(&format!("side item {}", i));
```

or

```rust
let mut my_frame = fltk::frame::Frame::new(0,0, 300, 100, None);
my_frame.set_label(&format!("side item {}", i));
```

Comment: Looks like a way better solution than mine.